# How do I install the Synergies mod?

Tags: mods, torchlight-2

I have downloaded the latest version of a Torchlight 2 synergies mod, and updated Torchlight 2 to version 1.9.5.1.  My question is, how can I install it on my PC? Since I'm not using Steam, so its only an offline game.

I've saved it into the Mods and Modsave folders, but it's still not working. I've also tried the Torchlight2 Mod Launcher, but that didn't help, either?

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: According to the installation instructions I can find, you need to dump it into the PAKS folder.

Comment: The easiest way is to subscribe to it on the Steam Workshop

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta OP says he isn't on Steam though.

Comment: @DomenikVanBuskirk He pirated the game. Look at comments of my answer.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta Ahh, I didn't see there was more comments

Comment: Note to closers: the asker might have pirated the game, but that doesn't invalidate the question; it's still something future readers might run into.  We don't support answers that advocate piracy, but instructions on how to install mods is still something useful to keep around.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [instructions I found](http://www.moddb.com/mods/synergiesmod/tutorials/how-to-install-a-mod-for-torchlight-2) for this mod, it needs to be installed into the PAKS folder, not Mods or Modsave.

> The hardest thing about installing mods for Torchlight 2 pre-guts is knowing where your PAK directory is.
>   it will either be in 1 of the 2 following places,  For RUNIC downloaded Torchlight 2 it should be:
>
> C:\Program Files\Torchlight II\PAKS
>
> for STEAM downloaded Torchlight 2 it should be: (either x86 or non x86 depending on your 64bit?)
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Torchlight II\PAKS

Comment: That is pre guts and therefore, outdated. If you bought the game legitimately and updated the game, which you are forced to by either Steam or the games launcher, my instructions work. He just does not have a legit copy of it, that is why it does not work.

Comment: @JohnDoeSanta I'm just pointing out the instructions that come with the mod.  I figure it's worth a shot.  If they're incorrect, the makers should really update those directions.

Comment: Torchlight II is also available via the GOG.com website.

Answer (score 0):

Installing mods for Torchlight 2 is fairly easy:

Put the folder of the mod into `Documents\my games\runic games\torchlight 2\mods` and then launch ModLauncher.exe from the Torchlight 2 game folder, activate the mod and run Torchlight 2. It is important to preserve the folder the mod lives in. So for example the mod respec potions, the final folder path is `Documents\my games\runic games\torchlight 2\mods\respec potion\respec_potion.mod`

The easiest way however is just to subscribe to the mods you want on Steam Workshop.

Comment: Sorry sir I didnt work also :( Can you please give me a sample instructions on how to do it? i mean other instructions? because your answer doesnt work.

Comment: This is my files sir i have a winrar called SYNERGIESV2189.zip and it contains SYNERGIES.MOD now my question is how can i use that? since the mod and modsave doesnt do anything in my game. how can i put the proper folders for this?

Comment: @CrixalisPaul Do you have Torchlight 2 on Steam?

Comment: No i dont have steam. i only use torchlight 2 that is offline

Comment: @CrixalisPaul Well, as I wrote, go to Documents\my games\runic games\torchlight 2\mods\ and put the file you have into a folder called "Synergies". That should do it.

Comment: This is my folder location C:\User\Paul\My Games\runic games\torchlight 2\mods that what i did. I put that in the files in that location but still nothing happens


:\User\Paul\My Games\runic games\torchlight 2\mods\Synergies then put the file? I already done this but still nothing happens.

Comment: @CrixalisPaul Are you sure you have launched the game via the modlauncher and actually enabled the mod?

Comment: i already done that sir. install the mod then open the modlauncher then select that then still nothing happens

Comment: @CrixalisPaul Do you have a legit copy of the game? As in did you buy it?

Comment: Im sorry my installer of TL2 is pirated :(

Comment: Well then we can't help you. Only legitimate copies are supported.